# Кодировка строки в Base64

Tags: c#, base64

Есть строка , необходимо её закодировать в Base64, как на [этом](https://www.base64encode.org/) сайте

Есть ли какая нибудь функция для этого?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string)

Encode

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

Decode

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```